# kvm template creation issue

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I want to create a template for multiple vm deployment from a existing image. I basically have a "template" vm ready with image in qcow2 format at path "/kvm/template.qcow2". I have heard about "virt-sysprep" which can modify hostname, ssh host keys, and etc. -- all packages are installed.

When I try to run the basic "virt-sysprep" command, I get a "no operating system found" error.  My Host Machine is Centos 6.9 , and guest vm is Centos7.

```
[root@ns0 kvm]# virt-sysprep --format qcow2 -a template.qcow2
Examining the guest ...
virt-sysprep: no operating systems were found in the guest image
[root@ns0 kvm]#
[root@ns0 kvm]#
[root@ns0 kvm]# ls -lh | grep template.qcow2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16G Aug 16 05:27 template.qcow2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I resolved it, it basically requires your VM partition to be not on LVM. i.e it should be vda1, vda2, sda1, etc.